# Slider in windows phone 8 want in round shape is it possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

Hi I'm new to windows phone my boss asked me do a slider that is round. For windows phone 8 so that i can use like a clock etc.. is there any possible way to acheive it .

In windows phone the slider control is in like a BAR i want it in round is there any style for that or any other control like slider that is round

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer properly. Please specify details and show at least mock-up of the desired result.

Comment: In windows phone the slider control is in like a BAR i want it in round is there any style for that or any other control like slider that is round

Comment: there is a product called - Expression Blend. It is designed to customize XAML and make controls/forms of any shape and color you want. Try it out

Comment: Can You post a sample how to use expression blend and sample code for getting a round slider .                                                             Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Also keep in mind that any circular toggleswitch you create will deviate from the platform. Don't just try to make your Windows Phone app look like iOS or Android.

Comment: A bar with rounded corners or a circular slider? Please provide a clear image of the result you want.

Comment: I think the OP wants something like this: http://www.winbeta.org/sites/default/files/newsimages/winblueappalarm2.jpg. It is already used in Windows 8 Alarm application.

Comment: Atlast I got the control it is Radial-Slider    and the link is https://github.com/SubsonicDesign/Windows-Phone-Radial-Slider. Thanks one and all

Comment: Have you looked into Telerik's RAD Controls for windows phone? The license is cheap and it does stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use arc shape and provide the angle based on user touch with in a specific bound.